# How to parse the double quotes CSV value and assign to JSON object?

Tags: jquery, json

Hi i have CSV string as below but when i use `spilt(',')` it create a problem as my CSV value looks like as below:

```
FirstName,LastName,Company,Website,Designation,Linkedin,Email,Phone,City,State,Country,TechArea,FirmType,FirmSize,LastContactDate,NextContactDate,LeadDescription,OwnerNotes,ReminderDate,AdminNotes,LeadStatus
Andrew,O'Connor,Goulston & Storrs PC,https://www.goulstonstorrs.com,Associate,,aoconnor@goulstonstorrs.com,(617) 574-4153,Boston,,USA,,,,,,,,,,
Lawrence,Cogswell,"Hamilton, Brook, Smith & Reynolds, P.C",https://www.hbsr.com,Principal,,Lawrence.Cogswell@hbsr.com,(617) 607-5907,"Boston, MA",,,,,,,,,,,,
```

In Notepad++  this double quotes appear while in Excel it make all in single cell.

Here `"Hamilton, Brook, Smith & Reynolds, P.C"` this is single value of JSON key pair but my parse function treat it separate values using `split(',')`. please help me out.

Below is my CSV parsing and making JSON of that Function.

```
function convertToJson(inputCsv){

    //var csv is the CSV file with headers
  var userid = $('#upload-lead-button').val();
  console.log(userid);
  var lines=inputCsv.split("\r\n").slice(0, -1);
  var result = [];

  var headers=lines[0].split(",");

  for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){

      var obj = {};

    // Check if the line has inverted double quotes start and end
    // Example 
    // Lawrence,Cogswell,"Hamilton, Brook, Smith & Reynolds,P.C",https://www.hbsr.com,Principal,,Lawrence.Cogswell@hbsr.com,(617) 607-5907,"Boston, MA",,,,,,,,,,,,

      var currentline=lines[i].split(",");

    for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){

        var str = currentline[j]

        // var str1 = ''

        // str = str.trim()

        // if( str.startsWith('"') ){

        //   // str = str.replace(/^\"/, '');
        //   // str = str.replace(/\"$/, '');
        //   str1 = + str

        //   continue

        // }          

          obj[headers[j]] = str;


    }

    obj["userid"] = userid;
    result.push(obj);

  }
  console.log(result);
  //return result; //JavaScript object
  return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON

}
```

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you use a CSV parsing library for this, such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser

Comment: i think regular expression or  doing something before `var currentline=lines[i].split(",");` can do this

Comment: the problem is Double quotes earlier i was thinking special characters, which i found using notepad++

Comment: i cannot use npm in my shared hosting

Comment: Then don't use NPM, just download the file from GIT and reference it

Comment: is there any other solution to solve above problem

Comment: Yeah, you could roll your own CSV parser but I'm sure would be some syntax which would break yours. There are already lots of good parsers available which meet all standards so you don't need to waste your time with it.

Comment: can i do to get substring between `,"` and `",` which can be treated as single value,

Comment: If you really wanted to, yes, but the bigger problem is splitting the string by `,` yet ignoring the `,` characters which are contained within quotes.

Comment: I just want to get rid of this short problem

Comment: That's the thing, it's not a short problem. However it has been solved hundreds of times by CSV parsers which is why I'm suggesting you use one.

Comment: yes this `substring between ," and ",` will be done prior to spilt

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you support your suggestion with some simple example as these things are new to me

Comment: It's literally the first thing I commented

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i tried to answer my question please see it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you explain how i can use npm csv parser in localhost

Comment: Everything is in the first link I gave you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser#usage. Any information I provide would merely be copying that

Comment: I mean where to put that `const csv = require('csv-parser')` in my single jaascript file, is it i need to download manualy and make same name file from github and save in root directory of my file

Comment: also there is no option to use CLI for me i am using sublime text to code the script

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above problem.

In this i tried to skip the spilt for the CSV row line which has `"`.

```
function convertToJson(inputCsv){

    //var csv is the CSV file with headers
  var userid = $('#upload-lead-button').val();
  console.log(userid);
  var lines=inputCsv.split("\r\n").slice(0, -1);
  var result = [];

  var headers=lines[0].split(",");

  for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){

      var obj = {};

    // Check if the line has inverted double quotes start and end
    // Example 
    // Lawrence,Cogswell,"Hamilton, Brook, Smith & Reynolds,P.C",https://www.hbsr.com,Principal,,Lawrence.Cogswell@hbsr.com,(617) 607-5907,"Boston, MA",,,,,,,,,,,,

    // IF DOUBLE QUOTES ARE NOT THERE THEN IN CURRENT LINE THEN SKIP  

    if(lines[i].includes('"')){

      var str1 = lines[i]

      var arr = CSVtoArray(str1)

      for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){

          var str = arr[j]   

          obj[headers[j]] = str;       

      }       

    }else{

      var currentline=lines[i].split(","); 

      for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){

          var str = currentline[j]   

          obj[headers[j]] = str;        

      }

    }

    obj["userid"] = userid;
    result.push(obj);

  }
  console.log(result);
  //return result; //JavaScript object
  return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON

}


// Return array of string values, or NULL if CSV string not well formed.
function CSVtoArray(text) {
    var re_valid = /^\s*(?:'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|[^,'"\s\\]*(?:\s+[^,'"\s\\]+)*)\s*(?:,\s*(?:'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|[^,'"\s\\]*(?:\s+[^,'"\s\\]+)*)\s*)*$/;
    var re_value = /(?!\s*$)\s*(?:'([^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*)'|"([^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*)"|([^,'"\s\\]*(?:\s+[^,'"\s\\]+)*))\s*(?:,|$)/g;
    // Return NULL if input string is not well formed CSV string.
    if (!re_valid.test(text)) return null;
    var a = [];                     // Initialize array to receive values.
    text.replace(re_value, // "Walk" the string using replace with callback.
        function(m0, m1, m2, m3) {
            // Remove backslash from \' in single quoted values.
            if      (m1 !== undefined) a.push(m1.replace(/\\'/g, "'"));
            // Remove backslash from \" in double quoted values.
            else if (m2 !== undefined) a.push(m2.replace(/\\"/g, '"'));
            else if (m3 !== undefined) a.push(m3);
            return ''; // Return empty string.
        });
    // Handle special case of empty last value.
    if (/,\s*$/.test(text)) a.push('');
    return a;
};
```